# How can I get a downloaded file original URI (not local)

Tags: android, download, uri

The code below gets the list of downloaded files:

```
File f = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);        File[] listOfDownloadedFiles = f.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfDownloadedFiles.length; i++) {
  //deal with each file for example:
  String fileName = listOfDownloadedFiles[i].getName();
}
```

I know there is a DownloadManager that can provide many details regarding a downloaded file (status, title, uri, localuri etc.).

I would like to know how can I join between the two programmatically?

Meaning, I would like to get all details that the DownloadManager provides regarding each and every file that exist on Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS.
Somehow the code to fetch data from DownloadManage:

```
query = new DownloadManager.Query();

downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

query.setFilterByStatus((DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED)|DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED|DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING|DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING);

c = downloadManager.query(query);

if(c.moveToFirst()){

...
}
```

always return false;

Thanks a lot in advance.

p.s.: I have tried all statuses for the query.setFilterByStatus(including DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCEEDED), also each one separately but still always false.

Comment: "I would like to get all details that the DownloadManager provides regarding each and every file that exist on Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS" -- there is no requirement for `DownloadManager` to have "details" regarding any of the files in that directory, let alone all of them. Apps can use `DownloadManager` to download files to other locations, and apps can put files in `DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` without involving `DownloadManager`.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. But is there a way\Query\API to get the location where a file was downloaded from(URL, attachment in an email etc.)?

Comment: I cannot speak for what `DownloadManager` might publicize, but you certainly cannot get it for arbitrary other apps. Apps that publish this sort of information are sources of privacy (and occasionally security) leaks, and their developers occasionally get sued as a result.